# Pass variables of a function to other function in a controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller that has the next functions:

```
class controller {

    function __construct(){

    }

    function myfunction(){
        //here is my variable
        $variable="hello"
    }


    function myotherfunction(){
        //in this function I need to get the value $variable
        $variable2=$variable 
    }

}
```

I thanks for your answers.  How can I pass variables of a function to other function in a controller of codeigniter?

Comment: Also, depending on whether or not `myotherfunction` should be callable through a url, you can name it with an underscore so it won't be available by default, such as `private function _myotherfunction(){}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can set $variable as an attribute in you class;

```
class controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $variable = 'hola';

    function __construct(){

    }

    public function myfunction(){
        // echo out preset var
        echo $this->variable;

        // run other function
        $this->myotherfunction();
        echo $this->variable;
    }

    // if this function is called internally only change it to private, not public
    // so it could be private function myotherfunction()
    public function myotherfunction(){
        // change value of var
        $this->variable = 'adios';
    }

}
```

This way *variable* will be available to all functions/methods in your controller class. Think OOP not procedural.

Comment: it's a great idea, however, when in mymotherfunction(), i am going to print the variable, don't show the value, the page is in white.  

localhost/myproject/controller/myotherfunction  (don't print echo $this->variable), will be to load some in the constructor?  
thanks. I'm sorry my english.

Comment: sorry, can't understand. If you just want to print the variable(why are you doing this from a controller?), just do echo $this->variable;     Or are you getting the infamous Codeigniter white screen of death?

Comment: @cabita If you want to send me your code, I'll take a look at it and send it back (hopefully working)

Comment: echo $this->variable don't print.  Here my code:  <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class test extends CI_Controller {
public $variable;
    function __Construct() {
        parent::__construct();
  
    }

    function myfn1() {
        $this->variable = 'hola';
        
    }

    function myfn2() {
        
        $variable2= $this->variable;
        echo $variable2;
        echo $this->variable;
    }

}

?>

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have edited my main answer to show you the code. I would recommend having a look at how OOP works. Also this would work the same for your models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your clarification.  I'll review the concepts about OOP.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a parameter for`myOtherFunction` and then simply pass the value from `myFunction()`:

```
function myFunction(){
    $variable = 'hello';
    $this->myOtherFunction($variable);
}

function myOtherFunction($variable){
    // $variable passed from myFunction() is equal to 'hello';
}
```

Comment: Hello.  I put the next code:
  function myfn1() {
        $variable = 'hola';
        $this->myfn2($variable);
    }

    function myfn2($variable) {
        
        echo $variable;
       
    }
and I appears the next error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for testdropdown::myfn2()

Filename: controllers/testdropdown.php

Line Number: 20
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: variable

Filename: controllers/testdropdown.php

Line Number: 22

Thanks for your help.